# UILabel divides single word

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uilabel

Good day folks,
Actually I'm going crazy, I did everything I could in order to solve this simple problem.

[image]

As you see, a simple label in a narrow space causes the single word "Verification" to be separated into two lines which is not acceptable of course.

I know that I could make number of lines only 1 and this will decrease font size, I tried all wraps modules and all fails.

What can I do to display the label as "Verification Process" without any separation of a single word? (I accept even shrinking font size or clipping last word).

Comment: is your label width is enough to accommodate the word?

Comment: Actually not, it's in a specified region.

Comment: presumably you have some constraint where you want the font size to be as big as possible across different screen sizes? so you don't want to just reduce the point size manually?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is default setting

[image]

Does these two settings below meet your needs?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude, first solution saved me:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with clipping of the words, then you can set the lines property of your label to 1. Or you want to reduce the font size that also can be done using storyboard property inspector. Hope this will help.

please try this. 
my testLabel and number of lines equal to 2.

```
self.testLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.testLabel.text = @"verificaton process";
```

Comment: Decreasing font size does not guarantee that such single word clipping won't occur.

Comment: Besides, I need multiple lines as it's multiple word.

Comment: Answer Edited please check.

Comment: if this doesn't work, i think your label is not getting enough space to adjust its width according to the words in it.

Comment: hmm, actually wordwrapping clip the word in the middle so it may appear like that (Verific)